# volume up/down reset after unplugging headphones

Tags: 11.10, headphones, volume-control

If I use Fn+VolumeUp/Down key combination to turn down the volume in my laptop, and then unplug the headphones from it, the volume goes back to what it was before. Has anyone noticed this bug? How can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is probably the reason why this is implemented as such. It works for me for 11.10.